# wireshark 802.11 wlan_radio.duration wlan_radio.preamble

Tags: wireshark, wifi

I am using wireshark in linux to capture 802.11 packet. When I see the resolution result, I see the **durationt**, **preamble**, then I find it is actually **wlan_radio.duration**, **wlan_radio.preamble**. wlan_radio.preamble is matched with the 802.11 protocol, and its meaning is obvious. But what does wlan_radio.duration mean? When I use (frame length - radiotaoheader length)*8/data rate, then plus preamble time, it is not equal to duration?
So, what does wlan_radio.duration mean in wireshark? How/where can I find its definition?

Answer (score 1):

**wlan_radio.preamble** is duration of the PLCP or preamble in microseconds, calculated from PHY data.

**wlan_radio.duration** is total duration of the frame in microseconds, including any preamble or PLCP header
and it calculated from the frame length, modulation and other PHY data.

This info you can find in [packet-ieee80211-radio.c](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-ieee80211-radio.c)